# c# to vb.net convsersion

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I am trying to convert a block of c# to vb.

I used the service at developerfusion.com to do the conversion, but when I paste it into Visual Studio, it is complaing about the "Key" statements("Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.' ").

I played around with the code for a few hours trying to get around that, but everything I did only led to more errors.

So I started to wonder if the conversion at developerfusion was ever correct.

Here is the c# to vb.net.

I am not sure where "Key" is coming from and was wondering if someone could enlighten me.

Thanks!

From

```
var combinedResults  = 
cars.Select(c=>new carTruckCombo{ID=c.ID,make=c.make,model=c.model})
.Union(tracks.Select(t=>new carTruckCombo{ID=t.ID,make=t.make,model=t.model}));
```

To

```
Dim combinedResults = cars.[Select](Function(c) New carTruckCombo() With { _
Key .ID = c.ID, _
Key .make = c.make, _
Key .model = c.model _
}).Union(tracks.[Select](Function(t) New carTruckCombo() With { _
Key .ID = t.ID, _
Key .make = t.make, _
Key .model = t.model _
}))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `Key`

do this instead:

```
    Dim combinedResults = cars.Select(Function(c) New carTruckCombo() With { _
    .ID = c.ID, _
        .make = c.make, _
        .model = c.model _
     }).Union(tracks.Select(Function(t) New carTruckCombo() With { _
        .ID = t.ID, _
        .make = t.make, _
        .model = t.model _
     }))
```

As a side-note, this converter always worked better for me whenever i needed it:

http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Just use `Select` instead of `[Select]`.

Comment: The question is what is the significance of `Key` and you did not explain that at all.  -1.

Comment: @pseudocoder - ...sheesh... thanks...though I'm guessing by that big green tick on my answer the OP was more than happy with my answer. Someone else explained the `key` though didn't give a working example of code. you going to wander over and downvote him too?

Comment: @Darren Don't take it personally.  Your answer is technically correct, I just don't consider it useful because you never explained why you felt your example was the best answer.  The user who posted the question may not have been interested in an explanation (just an answer), but you can bet that people who look at this QA in the future will want an explanation.

Comment: @pseudocoder - not taking it personally. Just don't think it warranted an actual downvote, though that's up to you and every other user here. By down-voting you're essentially saying that the answer is either wrong or unhelpful. Like I say though, up to you and everyone else.

Comment: Also, a very nice converter, that works both ways (plus ruby and python): http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 5):

In C#, when creating an anonymous type, it generates an `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementation for you using all the properties of your anonymous type.

VB.NET does something similar, but it requires you to put the [`Key` modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531349%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on the properties of your anonymous type.

C# "just does it" where VB.NET gives you the flexibility to define which properties are used in equality. Since C# uses all of the properties, the converter is giving you `Key` on everything so equality works the same.

OK, so that's the backstory of the `Key` modifier, so what's wrong with your conversion?

The converter seems to incorrectly assume you are using an anonymous type, but you're not. Your type is `carTruckCombo` so they `Key` modifiers don't work. Removing the `Key` modifier would fix the problem since you have a well defined class where you can implement your equality there.

Comment: This is the best answer because it actually explains the conversion problem and the language element to which the question pertains.